# Regular expression to remove certain characters after nth index value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

We are working on a form validation code snippet where jQuery masking plugin has been used to enforce validation on user input.

Masking Pattern used with zip code field is **99999?-9999** where everything is optional after "?".

Problem occurs when user fill up the form using autofill feature in chrome[i.e. double click on input field and select value] and submit the form. On form submission, zip code value is coming as **23455-____** which includes masking pattern characters as well i.e. hypen & underscore.

Refer attached screenshot after using autofill feature. http://inft.ly/3mmtNdA

If optional characters contains Hypen (-) and underscore(_) then those needs to be removed before submitting it to server. I am trying to use regex but didn't find anything which checks for specific characters after 5th index item and then remove those.

Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: what do you have so far? Can you give a few examples for a valid and unvalid zip codes (with special & unusual cases)

Comment: use on input function and then take the string into a javascript variable and then use str_replace for removing hyphen and underscore

Comment: as masking pattern written, first zip code must contain atleast 5 digits and after that everything is optional. Masking plugin prevent user to input anything less then 5 digits.

Comment: @sonamgupta you are right but i am struggling to find a regex which removes specific characters after 5th index item

Comment: str = str.replace(/_|-/g, ""); use this here str is your string

Comment: @sonamgupta In this case, what if user fills all 9 digits i.e. 99999-9999. Given regex will remove "-" hyphen which makes zip code invalid on sever end. Problem is to remove these characters after 5th digit.

Comment: first replace the hyphen and underscore and then use rtrim for removing extra digits

Comment: another way is explode string $str = array_shift(explode('-', $str)); and use first one or get substring like this  $str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '-'));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80726/discussion-between-lokesh-yadav-and-sonam-gupta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply strip the trailing underscores or dashes from the string like so:

```
var str = '12345-_____';
str.replace(/[-_]+$/, ''); // "12345"

var str = '12345-123__';
str.replace(/[-_]+$/, ''); // "12345-123"
```

Answer (score 2):

As you first five characters are numbers you can catch those in a capture group. Check if those are followed by (-) or (_) and replace those.

You would do this with the following regex:

```
str.replace(/(\d{5})[\-_](.*)/, '$1$2');
```

First you create a capture group to save the first five digits `(\d{5})`. Then you look for the characters you want to delete `[\-_]`. After that you capture the rest of your string `(.*)`.

Now you can replace your string with the to capture groups `'$1$2'` and you are done.

Comment: it is not always first five characters are digits. It depends on the masking pattern applied on zip code. For ex. canadian zip code is alphanumeric. So, i need to read masking pattern first to get the index of "?" then pass this index to regular expression to remove special characters after index value.

To overcome this combinations, i was searching for a regex pattern which returns string after 5th index value. For e.g. if string is "23345-____" then that regex should search for "-" & "" after 5th digit.